# How to add new fields into an existing entity in android using ormLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

**OLD ENTITY** : I had a entity and I forgot to add @DatabaseField annotation on some of the fields

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Card {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(unique = true)
    private String cardNumber;
    @DatabaseField
    private String nameOnCard;
    private String ccv;
    private String validFrom;
    private String validTill;
    private String pin;
    //Required by ormLite
    public Card() {
    }
//skipped the getter setters below
}
```

I have a class which writes the configuration, here is the code.

```
package net.udevs.db;
import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteConfigUtil;
import net.udevs.entity.Card;

public class OrmLiteSqlLiteConfigGenerator extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
    private final static Class<?>[] entityClasses=new Class[]{EmailAccount.class, Card.class};
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
        writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt",entityClasses);
    }
}
```

The Config File which was generated is below & by looking at it I know that the fields aren't getting updated in the database.

```
#
# generated on 2016/01/14 01:13:56
#
# --table-start--
dataClass=net.udevs.entity.Card
tableName=card
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=cardNumber
unique=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=nameOnCard
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

**NEW ENTITY :** Now I have added the @DatabaseField annotation which were missing.

```
public class Card {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(unique = true)
    private String cardNumber;
    @DatabaseField
    private String nameOnCard;
    @DatabaseField
    private String ccv;
    @DatabaseField
    private String validFrom;
    @DatabaseField
    private String validTill;
    @DatabaseField
    private String pin;

    public Card() {
    }

    public Card(int id, String cardNumber, String nameOnCard, String ccv, String validFrom, String validTill, String pin) {

        this.id = id;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.nameOnCard = nameOnCard;
        this.ccv = ccv;
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
        this.validTill = validTill;
        this.pin = pin;
    }
//skipped the getter setters below
}
```

& then I ran the OrmLiteConfigUtil class again, but the configuration file didn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add @DatabaseField annotation to the missing fields and increment the database version, then in onUpgrade method do this

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion == 1) {
            try {
                Dao dao = getCardDao();
                dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `Card` ADD COLUMN ccv STRING;");
                dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `Card` ADD COLUMN validFrom STRING;");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Error ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally run the OrmLiteConfigUtil and the config text file will should change.

In this way you don´t have to erase the database and lose the data.

Comment: in this case i have to manually write the sql code in the executeRaw() for the new columns everytime? And thank you this will certainly help :)

Comment: Only one time.

Imagine you have the table "Card" with the columns A and B and the database version is 1.If you want add the column C, you have to increment the database version and write the example code for "onUpgrade" method.

In this way the executeRaw is only called one time and your database in the version 2 will contains the column C in the table Card.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for adding new column:

1. Update your database version first i.e from 1 to 2.
2. In `onUpgrade()` method your can drop previous tables:

   ```
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
   {
       try
       {
           TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, ABC.class, true);
           TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, XYZ.class, true);
       }
       catch (SQLException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       onCreate(database, connectionSource);
   }
   ```
3. In `OnCreate()`, create table again:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
       try
       {
           TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ABC.class);
           TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, XYZ.class);
       }
       catch (SQLException ex)
       {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
4. In your ABC table, you can add another column:

   ```
   @DatabaseField(columnName = AppConstants.TABLE_COLUMN_IS_SHOW_AUTOGRAPH, defaultValue = "false")
   private boolean mShowAutoGraph;
   ```
5. Note: Make sure to edit your `ormlite_config.txt` file with these values:

   ```
   fieldName=mShowAutoGraph // field name used in table
   columnName=show_autograph // key used in AppConstants.TABLE_COLUMN_IS_SHOW_AUTOGRAPH
   defaultValue=false
   # --field-end--
   # --table-fields-end--
   # --table-end--
   ```

   Here make sure you end table rather with `--end--` tag. Remove tag of end from previous entry of this table. If you don't do it, you will never be able to see your column.

Comment: drop table is not a proper solution for an app in production.